# Math course after calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I'm really enjoying calculus and linear algebra, and I think there are my best subjects. Multivariable calculus was especially interesting, and I hope I can continue my studies in calculus. I'm intending to major in math, and I'm planning to take rigorous proof courses in the future, but do you have any suggestions for any computation-heavy proof courses? I prefer to take computation-heavy proofs than abstract proofs. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Combinatorics and graph theory are both good choices, although there are plenty of problems that are abstract in both of these fields, as well. Maybe an advanced statistics class?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You might like number theory

Comment: "Computation heavy" makes me think of programming (e.g. linear, quadratic or non-linear). Often there are applied mathematics courses which cover these topics and include the rigorous backing

Comment: Perhaps numerical analysis, which blends into applied functional analysis at the advanced level (functional analysis being, roughly speaking, calculus in infinite dimensional spaces).

Comment: If you want to major in math you'll need to be comfortable with abstract proofs as well.